# display temperature realtime with node js websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I have temperature sensor ds18b20 and i got the reading successfully, how do I send this value to connected clients as the temperature changes.

```
socket.emit('Temperature', TempValue() );
```

using this on `connection` gets executed only once, I need to continuously send to the client this would be displayed on an HTML page.

Comment: Could you just wrap it in a `setInterval`, and check the temperature every, for example, 500 ms
`setInterval(() => socket.emit('Temperature', TempValue()), 500)`
or
`socket.setInterval(() => socket.emit('Temperature', TempValue()), 500)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a somewhat similar system that controls attic fans based on a couple temperature sensors.  What I do is the following:

1. I have a polling interval local to the server using `setInterval()` that reads the temperature sensors.  This interval is independent of any of the connections, it's something the server does on behalf of all connections.
2. When the app first starts up, the first temperature is sent to any connected clients and I store what that temperature value was that I last sent.
3. Then on the next polling loop, I compare the new current temperature value to the last temperature value that I sent.  When those two values differ by some pre-determined amount, then I broadcast a new temperature value to all connected clients with `io.emit()` and save the new value that I just sent as the new comparison value.
4. If they don't differ by enough, then I don't send anything and don't save the new temperature and keep checking in each polling interval waiting for the temperature value to differ enough to warrant sending it to the client.

In this way, I only send a new temperature to the client when it's actually different enough from the previous value to matter and be worth using some bandwidth to send.

Comment: yes  `ds18b20.temperature('28-031397798ac6', function(err, value) {
    temperature = value;
    io.emit('temperature',temperature);
 }
  }); `

Comment: @reputationX - Is this comment an additional question or you're saying you figured it out now?